# How to set equal height in carousel by bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make the height of columns equal? I know that bootstrap has 'equal' attribute, can it be implemented in carousel? Or I should set a height by rem in css?
Here is my carousel:

```
 <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel py-3 py-md-4 slide" data-type="multi" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item carousel-item active">
                                <div class="row equal">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 d-flex offset-2">
                                        <div class="single-box px-5">
                      
                                            <div class="white mt-0 my-5 pt-sm-0 pr-2">Some text about stuff.jnmla;sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item carousel-item">
                                <div class="row equal">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 d-flex offset-2">
                                        <div class="single-box px-5">
                                            <div class="white mt-0 my-5">Another topic
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                        <a class="carousel-control left angle-left carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">
                            <img src='images/left.png' >
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right angle-right carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">
                            <img src='images/right.png' >
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

I don't really want to set a height in css,'cause the text in columns may be changed, so that it won't fit in the column

Comment: set height and width for images in carousel...

Comment: @DrJManish I don't have images in carousel. Just text